# Working with datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a huge dataframe. Below is a small example:

```
Date        Timing  Day_number
17.03.2016     8       1
17.03.2016     8       2
17.03.2016     8       3
17.03.2016     8       4
17.03.2016     8       5
17.03.2016     8       6
17.03.2016     8       7
17.03.2016     8       8
30.08.2016     3       1
30.08.2016     3       2
30.08.2016     3       3
31.05.2016     3       1
31.05.2016     3       2
31.05.2016     3       3
...
```

I need to add a new column.  I look at what value is in the column "Timing". For example if the value is 8, then I look at the date and add one day in each line for this case. The result is eight rows with dates from 17.03.2016 to 24.03.2016. The value in the column "Timing" can be different. Dates are also different. For this example, I should have something like this:

```
Date        Timing     Day_number      Distribution_of_days
17.03.2016     8          1                 17.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          2                 18.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          3                 19.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          4                 20.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          5                 21.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          6                 22.03.2016  
17.03.2016     8          7                 23.03.2016
17.03.2016     8          8                 24.03.2016
30.08.2016     3          1                 30.08.2016
30.08.2016     3          2                 31.08.2016        
30.08.2016     3          3                 01.09.2016    
31.05.2016     3          1                 31.05.2016
31.05.2016     3          2                 01.06.2016
31.05.2016     3          3                 02.06.2016
...
```

At the same time I need to skip the weekend!

Pandas recognizes the value of a column "Date" as non-null object. Does this mean that he does not see them as dates?

Can someone help me? I can't deal with this task myself.

Comment: Totally unclear.

Comment: By default if I am not wrong, pandas recognizes dates as string so you better use [pandas.to_datetime](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) to convert the `Date` column to datetime values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.assign(Distribution_of_days=df['Date'] + df['Day_number'].apply(BDay))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Timing  Day_number Distribution_of_days
0  2016-03-17       8           1           2016-03-18
1  2016-03-17       8           2           2016-03-21
2  2016-03-17       8           3           2016-03-22
3  2016-03-17       8           4           2016-03-23
4  2016-03-17       8           5           2016-03-24
5  2016-03-17       8           6           2016-03-25
6  2016-03-17       8           7           2016-03-28
7  2016-03-17       8           8           2016-03-29
8  2016-08-30       3           1           2016-08-31
9  2016-08-30       3           2           2016-09-01
10 2016-08-30       3           3           2016-09-02
11 2016-05-31       3           1           2016-06-01
12 2016-05-31       3           2           2016-06-02
13 2016-05-31       3           3           2016-06-03
```

EDIT (He starts work on the current day):

```
df.assign(Distribution_of_days=df['Date'] + df['Day_number'].add(-1).apply(BDay))
```

Output:

```
         Date  Timing  Day_number Distribution_of_days
0  2016-03-17       8           1           2016-03-17
1  2016-03-17       8           2           2016-03-18
2  2016-03-17       8           3           2016-03-21
3  2016-03-17       8           4           2016-03-22
4  2016-03-17       8           5           2016-03-23
5  2016-03-17       8           6           2016-03-24
6  2016-03-17       8           7           2016-03-25
7  2016-03-17       8           8           2016-03-28
8  2016-08-30       3           1           2016-08-30
9  2016-08-30       3           2           2016-08-31
10 2016-08-30       3           3           2016-09-01
11 2016-05-31       3           1           2016-05-31
12 2016-05-31       3           2           2016-06-01
13 2016-05-31       3           3           2016-06-02
```

Comment: March 17, 2016 is a Thursday and two days you get Saturday.  The next business day is Monday, March 21, 2016.

Comment: Thank you! This works almost perfectly! But he begins from the next day in each case. For example if in a column "Date"  2016-05-31, then in the column "Distribution_of_days" the account starts from  2016-06-01. Is it possible to do so that it started on 2016-05-31?

Comment: I don't understand.  Do you wanto start your Day_number with 0 instead of one?

Comment: df.assign(Distribution_of_days=df['Date'] + df['Day_number'].add(-1).apply(BDay))

Answer (score 2):

This will make it work:

```
import pandas as pd

#this is just creation of your dataframe
data = '17.03.2016,8,1,17.03.2016,8,2,17.03.2016,8,3,17.03.2016,8,4,17.03.2016,8,5,17.03.2016,8,6,17.03.2016,8,7,17.03.2016,8,8,30.08.2016,3,1,30.08.2016,3,2,30.08.2016,3,3,31.05.2016,3,1,31.05.2016,3,2,31.05.2016,3,3'
data = data.split(',')
date = data[::3]
timing = [int(i) for i in data[1::3]]
day_number = [int(j) for j in data[2::3]]


#here is actual code
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': date, 'Timing': timing, 'Day_number': day_number})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df['Distribution_of_days'] = df.Date + pd.to_timedelta(df.Day_number-1, unit='D')
```